# Expand a list returned by a function to multiple columns (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that I'm trying to call on each row of a dataframe and I would like it to return 20 different numeric values and each of those be in a separate column of the original dataframe.

For example, this is not the function, but it if this will work the actual one will

```
def doStuff(x):
    return([x] * 5)
```

So this will just return the same number 5x. so if I have the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2]})
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

After calling

```
df = np.vectorize(doStuff)(df['A'])
```

It should end up looking like

```
   A  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `df.apply`, twice.

```
In [1254]: df['A'].apply(np.vectorize(doStuff)).apply(pd.Series)
Out[1254]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3
```

You may concatenate this with the original using `pd.concat(..., axis=1)`:

```
In [1258]: pd.concat([df, df['A'].apply(np.vectorize(doStuff)).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
Out[1258]: 
   A  0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

From pandas 0.23 you can use the `result_type` argument:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2]})

def doStuff(x):
    return([x] * 5)

df.apply(doStuff, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```